# Python Code with several functions, asks user for input, after input, code ends and doesn't execute

Tags: python

Below is my code. It will ask the user for their input. After putting in the required input and pressing enter it ends and doesn't go to the required function to execute. If someone could help me fix it, I would be most appreciative.

```
from statistics import mean
#headOfFile - prints the first 5 lines of the file passed in as a parameter
def headOfFile(myFile):
    return headOfFile
    f=open("textFile.txt", "r")
    for i in range(5):
        f.readline(5)
    print (i)
    f.close()
#tailOfFile - prints the last 5 lines of the file passed in as a paramete
def tailOfFile(myFile):
    return tailOfFile   
    f=open("textFile.txt","r")
    for i in range(5):
        f.readline(-5)
    print (i)
    
    f.close()
def wordCount(myFile):
    return wordCount
    f=open("textFile.txt", "rt")
    words = "textFile.txt".split()
    print ('Number of words in text file: ', len(words))
    file = open("textFile.txt", "r")
    lines = "textFile.txt"
    f.readline()
    print ("Number of lines in text file: ", len(lines))
    f.close()   
#stats - prints the smallest, largest, and average of the numbers in the file
def stats(myFile):
    return stats
    f=open("number.txt", "r")
    l=[ int(l) for l in input("number.txt").split(",")]
    minl = l[0]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] < minl:
 minl = l[i]
    print ("The smallest number in the list is: ",minl)
    maxl = l[0]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] > maxl:
            maxl = l[i]
    print ("The largest number in the list is: ", maxl)
    
    Average = sum(l) / float(len(l))
    my_list = ("number.txt")
    average =Average(my_list) 
    print ("Average of list is: ", average)
    f.close()
myFile = input("Enter the name of the first file you want to use(headOfFile, 
tailOfFile, wordCount, stats): ")
headOfFile(myFile)
tailOfFile(myFile)
wordCount(myFile)
```

Comment: Why is the first line in each of your functions a `return` statement?

Comment: You might want to read up on what [return statements](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/) do.

Comment: There are many problems with the code you show, the early return being the least of them. Please take some time to study more. And please don't write large and complex blocks of code without any kind of testing.

Comment: Yes, also a good point. No sense writing more functions until you've made sure the first one works.

Answer (score 4):

Your functions all start with a `return` statement, for some reason just returning a reference to the function itself. Hence the functions don’t do anything useful, as none of the rest of their code will be executed.